# How to move positions of OSes in grub 2?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub

I installed multiple OSes on my PC. When the grub bootloader appears, I want the order to be different. How can I change that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order that you see is determined by the order of the entries in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. You could edit that file, but it probably says at the top that you shouldn't edit it as the file automatically generated. My `grub.cfg` states in the header:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

In `/etc/grub.d` you'll have something like the following files:

```
00_header*        10_linux*       20_memtest86+*     40_custom*
05_debian_theme*  10_lupin*       30_os-prober*      41_custom*
06_mint_theme*    20_linux_xen*   30_uefi-firmware*  README
```

The numbers are used to influence the order of processing, and with that the order of the entries in your bootloader menu. E.g. if you do `mv 20_memtest86+ 07_memtest86+`, you'll get memtest as your first entry.

You might have to copy these files and edit them to get more finegrained control over the ordering. Especially `os-prober` might gather multiple entries.